# Loading tab contents with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, maps

I have webpage with tabs that switch between views. [Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/5WVc6/)

The issue is that the when the page is loading, it loads all the information from **all** tabs.

I wish to load the tab contents when the user switches tabs.

Current code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Tabs">
                <li class="active">
                <a href="#tab1-1" data-toggle="tab">TEXT1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#tab2-1" data-toggle="tab">TEXT2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#tab3-1" data-toggle="tab">TEXT3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1-1">
                    <img src="http://colmenarviejo.info/IMG/BANNER_300X300.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" class="img-polaroid">
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-1">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.614474,-111.926758&amp;num=1&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.609782,-111.936264&amp;spn=0.156382,0.205307&amp;z=11&amp;output=embed">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3-1">
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        <dt>City</dt>
                        <dd>Av. 1</dd>
                        <dt>Tel</dt>
                        <dd>(000)123456789</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript ([Plugin](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    e.target // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

How should I get started on loading the content, when the user clicks on the tab?

Comment: have you seen http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery `.load()` to load the content into the selected pane, and then show the pane once the content is successfully loaded.

Example: http://www.bootply.com/63891

Comment: Great, it's some like this i need it, but i try with google maps and don't work, i use some like this in the list   <li><a href="#profile" data-url="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.614474,-111.926758">Profile</a></li>

Comment: That is a problem with cross domain AJAX request

Comment: and how to fix that??,maybe add    URL += "&jsoncallback=?";